# Export and import search folders criteria option in outlook

Tags: microsoft-outlook

I have created several search folders in Outlook. I don't see this in OWA, and if I reconfigure outlook, I might need to recreate the same criteria again (waste of time). Is it possible to export the logic, which I created and import it into another system?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, we cannot export or import search folders in Outlook client. I'm afraid we need to manually recreate the search folder when you reconfigure your Outlook.